# Attach small winch to truck bed or rear bumper

Tags: truck, trailer, bumper, aftermarket-upgrade, boat

I have a 2010 1500 Silverado and a small [ATV winch](https://www.princessauto.com/en/2000-lb-12v-dc-winch/product/PA0009037144).

I want to use the winch to [pull a lightweight aluminum boat up a slight incline](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29137/launch-boat-on-a-pebble-beach).

[image]

[image]

---

I want to temporarily/occasionally attach the winch to the truck bed or rear bumper so that I can pull the boat and trailer up the incline to the truck.

- I want the winch to pull the trailer hitch so that it's ***above*** the truck hitch. Reason: When the trailer is in position, I want to let the trailer hitch *down* onto the truck hitch.

How can I temporarily attach the winch to the truck bed or bumper?

My priority is *quick & easy future installation*. It can be a relatively lightweight setup since the boat and trailer don't weigh much. For what it's worth, I have a [Back Rack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiqzk.png) installed on the truck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if I could attach the winch to the Back Rack:

1. On the bottom cross member, drill two holes in the middle of the square tube.
2. Install bolts into the holes. The heads of the bolts would be on the window-side of the rack.

[image]

3. Use the factory holes in the winch to attach the winch to the Back Rack. Thread a couple of wingnuts onto the bolts.

The winch would be positioned vertically, due to the placement of the factory holes in the winch plate.

---

**Edit:**

I wonder if winches are only designed to spool the cable when positioned horizontally. Maybe the cable would jam if the winch was mounted vertically.

Alternatively, I could use a [U-Bolt](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/buildex-square-u-bolt-carbon-steel-zinc-plated-3-x-2-in-0612014p.0612014.html?rq=u-bolt#srp) on the bottom bar of the Back Rack to attach the winch. That way, the winch would be positioned horizontally, as designed.

This is the U-Bolt I used: [Square U Bolt, Carbon Steel, Zinc-Plated, 3 x 2-in](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/buildex-square-u-bolt-carbon-steel-zinc-plated-3-x-2-in-0612014p.0612014.html?rq=U-bolt#srp)

Answer (score 2):

Your truck has stake pockets in the top of the side rails. You'll find a pair close to the tailgate and another pair close to the cab. (There may be others in an intermediate location.)

The stake pockets are sized to fit a standard 2x4, and stake pocket accessories made of steel or aluminum are available in the aftermarket.

Fabricate a cross-piece that can span between the top rails and engage the rearmost stake pockets. Mount the winch to the cross-piece permanently so that when you want to use it, you can simply slip the contraption into the stake pockets. No need to fumble with fasteners. A 2x8 or 2x10 would probably be strong enough, but for lighter weight you could probably cobble together a frame from U-channel fence posts or similar.

The high position should make it easier to lift the trailer onto the hitch.

Comment: Thanks! Are you picturing the 2x8 or 2x10 sitting A) *flat* or B) *on edge*?

Comment: @User1974 On edge, it's very easy to attach to 2x4s in the stake pockets, but you'll get some bowing when the winch takes a strain. Sitting flat, less chance of bowing but perhaps a little harder to measure and fasten *between* the stakes. Right angle corner braces / angle plates (using short screws) may be your best friend for this. I would do it in steel, but that's just me. Whatever works for you.

Comment: For our notes, the stake pockets on this truck are slightly smaller than a 2x4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y30sn.jpg. So I would need to cut the 3.5" dimension down to 2 5/8".

Comment: Alternatively, I wonder if I could use [stake pocket anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud2pV.png) with the anchor loops parallel to the tailgate. And then fasten a 2x8 (placed flat, not on edge) to the anchors via bolts. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjU6p.png. **Edit:** On closer inspection, there's a review on the [website](https://www.princessauto.com/en/1-pc-loop-around-truck-bed-stake-pocket-anchor/product/PA0008164105) that says, *"Goes in the sidewall anchor points, not the stake pockets on the top."* So those anchors wouldn't do what I want.

Comment: @User1974 Your stake pockets would accept a standard 2x3. Beyond that, construction possibilities are endless and limited only by your imagination. For more ideas and feedback, perhaps start a conversation in Chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=mechanics.stackexchange.com